# How to deploy multiple web apps on different ports in Tomcat 9?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I am trying to deploy a spring app on different port on Tomcat 9. What I want to achieve is to:
1. Leave default Tomcat config for other apps to deploy them in `webapps` folder on port 8080
2. Deploy only one spring app on port 8081 on root path

So for example:
`localhost:8080/app1`
`localhost:8080/app2`
[...]
`localhost:8081/`

I have created new folder for my second service: `/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps_8081/`
For the first service I left it in default location: `/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/`

Here is my `server.xml` file:

```
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>

  <Service name="Catalina_8081">
    <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8444" />
    <Engine name="Catalina_8081" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps_8081" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
```

**What I have tried so far and what were the results**

**Method 1: place war file in deployment folder**

1. When I put `myapp.war` file into `webapps` folder, it is being deployed without any issues on `localhost:8080/myapp`
2. When I put myapp.war file into `webapps_8081` folder, I get following errors:

```
07-Sep-2019 15:20:29.370 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps_8081/myapp.war]
07-Sep-2019 15:20:29.384 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception fixing docBase for context [/myapp]
 java.io.IOException: Unable to create the directory [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps_8081/myapp]
```

When I create this folder manually, then logs says that application has been deplyed, but folder is empty and deployment itself taking only 3 miliseconds.

3. When I rename the file to `ROOT.war` and place it into `webapps` folder, it is being deployed without any issues:

```
07-Sep-2019 15:23:50.845 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/ROOT.war]
07-Sep-2019 15:25:13.486 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TL$
07-Sep-2019 15:25:13.568 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/ROOT.war] has finished in [82,722] ms
```

But when opening `localhost:8080/` it's giving me 404 error

4. When I rename the file to `ROOT.war` and place it into `webapps_8081` folder, I get the same errors as in point no.2.

It looks like some problem with permissions to the folder which I created manually, but the rights are the same for both: `webapps` and `webapps_8081` (I have changed a group and owner to `tomcat` user for `webapps_8081`):

```
$ sudo ls -l
drwxrwxr-x 3 tomcat tomcat     4096 Sep  7 14:31 webapps
drwxrwxr-x 2 tomcat tomcat     4096 Sep  7 14:04 webapps_8081
```

**Method 2: use external content file**

As second method of deployment, I have tried to use Context file. I was following [Christopher's answer in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41284328/8864483)

I placed my war file outside of webapps folders: `/var/lib/tomcat9/myapp.war`

`myapp.xml` file:
`<Context docBase="/var/lib/tomcat9/myapp.war"></Context>`

1. I place `myapp.xml` in `/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/Catalina/localhost/osp.xml` - app is deployed successfuly on `localhost:8080/myapp`
2. I place `myapp.xml` in `/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/Catalina_8081/localhost/osp.xml`  - I get following errors:

```
07-Sep-2019 16:09:33.483 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/etc/tomcat9/Catalina_8081/localhost/myapp.xml]
07-Sep-2019 16:09:33.501 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception fixing docBase for context [/myapp]
 java.io.IOException: Unable to create the directory [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps_8081/myapp]
```

3. I rename `myapp.xml` to `ROOT.xml` and place it in `/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml` - as per logs, app is deplyed successfully

```
07-Sep-2019 16:16:36.411 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16 (Debian)]
07-Sep-2019 16:16:36.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml]
07-Sep-2019 16:18:06.839 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TL$
07-Sep-2019 16:18:06.923 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] has finished in [90,485] ms
```

But when opening `localhost:8080/` it's giving me 404 error

4. I rename `myapp.xml` to `ROOT.xml` and place it in `/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/Catalina_8081/localhost/ROOT.xml` - I get following errors:

```
07-Sep-2019 16:14:08.417 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/etc/tomcat9/Catalina_8081/localhost/ROOT.xml]
07-Sep-2019 16:14:08.434 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception fixing docBase for context []
 java.io.IOException: Unable to create the directory [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps_8081/ROOT]
```

So as you can see I have 2 main issues here.

**Question 1**
Why Tomcat cannot create new directories within `webapps_8081` ?
**Question 2**
Why do I get 404 error when an app is deployed as ROOT.war while it works well on regular mapping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow Tomcat war app to write in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827735/how-to-allow-tomcat-war-app-to-write-in-folder). The directory names look like you're running on Debian or derivative thereof, where you'll run into Debian's default sandboxing of tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problems.
First I have reinstalled Tomcat completely and removed all the leftovers, by following the steps described by Dung in this topic: [how to completely remove tomcat 7 from ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268520/how-to-completely-remove-tomcat-7-from-ubuntu-14-04). That resolved an issue with root mapping. So in the result I don't know what was causing that.

Permissions problem has been resolved by creating override.conf file described in [How to allow Tomcat war app to write in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56835997/8864483)